# schematics "spec": false not working on Ionic 4 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

How can I stop generating `.spec` file on `Ionic 4` app?

I have tried this: But it is not working. i.e. still it generates `.spec` file.

```
ionic g service services/MyService
```

*angular.json*

```
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:guard": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:module": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:service": {
      "spec": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `"spec": false` to `"skip-tests": true`.

Comment: No. Still the same result. `"@schematics/angular:service": {
      "skip-tests": true
    }` @R.Richards

Comment: Does `ionic g service services/MyService --skip-tests=true` work?

Comment: It's actually "skipTests": true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is going on here is that default ionic boilerplate for Angular sets `defaultCollection` to `@ionic/angular-toolkit`:

**angular.json**

```
"cli": {
   "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
},
```

So you have to provide those flags for `@ionic/angular-toolkit` specific options like:

```
"@ionic/angular-toolkit:service": {
  "spec": false, // or "skipTests": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not work `// or "skipTests": true`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have used this `"skip-tests": true`

Comment: Please see this too. This is on Ionic 5 app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961852/ionic-5-angular-9-spec-file-has-been-generated-even-though-spec-false-only-fo

Answer (score 0):

Just use: ionic g service services/apinasa --skip-tests

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please elaborate the reasoning of the subtle difference your proposed solution exhibits in comparison to the quite ancient comment by R. Richards. Because at first glance, yours seems to be a copy of that.